# How a token can identify unique android device remotely

Tags: android, firebase, ip, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a pretty noob here. I was trying Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications in android devices. For that I tried sending notifications to devices based on the token generated from `FirebaseInstanceIdService class`. But what I want to understand is how can just a token identify my android device remotely without any `ip address` information?

Furthermore not just based on tokens but even based on `Topics` it identifies the device correctly. How is that possible without any ip addressing scheme?

**Note: This might come as a vague question but any direction to solution would be nice.**

Comment: Firebase token is generated by google play services sitting in android devices, so google play services have a connection with firebase servers. Whenever a notification comes , firebase server knows to send notification to particular device.
There is one background service which is controlled by Android OS service , which continuously listens to the firebase servers.

Answer (score 0):

The firebase server doesn't need to know the IP of the device because it is the device that initiates the connection.  The firebase server I believe generates the token and gives it to the device.

(not sure about topics because I have not used them, but I expect the device will subscribe to topics it is interested in)

For sending notifications from your own server to a specific device via firebase, your server needs to know the device token. So typically when your app connects to firebase, it will communicate the token (instance id) it receives with your server in some way (determined by you).  Your server can then target a specific device using the token it received from your app.

The video in this article goes some way to explaining what is going on.  It is based on iOS but parts of it are relevant to Android.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/debugging-firebase-cloud-messaging-on.html